# How to identify which imageview will be selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing one application.

In that I have used the three `uiimageviews`.

And used the `UITapGesture` to open the photo library.

My problem is how to identify which imageview is tapped, for setting the selected image in photo library.

Please tell me how to identify that one?

Comment: may be duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330738/attach-gesturerecogniser-to-multiple-imageviews you have to give different tag to imageview and check aginst imageview tag

Answer (score 2):

Use tag property of imageview and then

```
-(void)doAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
NSLog(@"Imageview :%d",recognizer.view.tag)
```

}